# Howdo I use MATPOWER only for power flow?

Tags: matlab, matpower

Here is my question. I´m developing a genetic algorithm to optmize a distribution net by reducing it´s power losses, I´ve been trying to use Matpower since this "matlab´s plugin" already calculate the power flow, but my problem is that matpower tries to optimize it. I´d like to know if it is possible to use it only for power flow calculation and how could I do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just find the answer. It is quite simple, instead of using runopf() you can use runpf() for power flow analyses.